# Thingsboard PE user limit

Tags: thingsboard

I wanted to know if there are limits to the number of users in different types of the PE license.

In the pricing page of Thingsboard it only shows the number of devices and assets:
[image]

So I suppose that there is no limit for the users, but I wanted to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limitation on number of users. Please see the list of all limits here: https://thingsboard.io/products/paas/subscription/